# Can't load CSS file after form submitted in node js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

Let me give more details first. I use node's nodemailer to send emails from submitted info on form. When I had one recipient and one html body, which sends it all at once, was working fine. But when I put `mailOptions2` in a `for` loop so I'm able to send the email with the recipients and html bodies that are in different arrays. Then it still sends the emails and html contents differently how I wanted. But when the form is submitted, in the `/send` state it keeps loading and it ends up only loading the page's raw html, no css. I get this error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:489:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:496:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Ahmet Ömer\Desktop\Repairtechnician\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Ahmet Ömer\Desktop\Repairtechnician\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at done (C:\Users\Ahmet Ömer\Desktop\Repairtechnician\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1004:10)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Ahmet Ömer\Desktop\Repairtechnician\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\utils.js:26:13)
    at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)
```

I know there were posts on this error but could not know how to solve it in my case, since I am fairly beginner.

Nodejs:

```
app2.engine('handlebars', exphbs2());
app2.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Static folder
app2.use('/public', express2.static(path2.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app2.use('/', express2.static(path2.join(__dirname, '')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app2.use(bodyParser2.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app2.use(bodyParser2.json());

app2.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('services');
});

app2.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  let mailList = ['xyz', 'xyz@gmail.com'];
  let outputs = [
    `
    <div>
    </div>  
  `,
  `
   <div>
   </div>  
`];

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter2 = nodemailer2.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    port: 25,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'xyz@gmail.com', // senders email
        pass: 'xyz' // senders password
    },
    tls:{
      rejectUnauthorized:false
    }
  });

  for ( var i = 0; i < mailList.length; i++) {
      // setup email data with raw html
      let mailOptions2 = {
        from: '"xyz" <xyz@info.com>', // sender address
        to: mailList[i], // receiver or receivers
        subject: 'xyz', // Subject line
        html: outputs[i] // html body
    };

        // send mail with defined transport object
      transporter2.sendMail(mailOptions2, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer2.getTestMessageUrl(info));

        res.render('services', {msg2:'xyz'});
    });
  }
});
```

As I said, if I had not used a `for` loop for `mailOptions2` to pass different values to specified areas, it would've worked just fine.

Here's my structure of mentioned files if might help:

```
server.js
services.html
public
   css
      styles.css
```

Comment: Are you trying to keep users on one page while you send a post request that sends an email? After the post request do you want to change the style of the page? Try to update your question to give a clearer indication of what you're trying to achieve. You could just add your styles to the page, preface those styles that apply after the form is sent with `.form-sent`, and add the `.form-sent` class to a top tag (like body) on POST of the form...

Comment: I don't want to change anything, just want it stay the same. Because after the form is submitted, when the page loads, its just raw html because it doesn't load the css file. @duhaime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `res.render()` multiple time because `res.render` send the compiled html to the client. So you have to call `res.render` only when you want to send the final response to your client.

For this case you can use Promise to manage the sendMail callback:

```
// init this array outside the for loop
let sendMailPromises = [];

// this is inside the for loop
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    transporter2.sendMail(mailOptions2, (err, infos) => {
        if(err) reject(err)

        console.log('Mail sent %s', info.messageId);
        console.info('Preview URL: %s', nodeMailer2.getTest(info));
        resolve(infos)
    });

});
sendMailPromises.push(promise);

// this is after (and outside) the for loop.
Promise.all(sendMailPromises)
    .then(() => {
        res.render(mailOptions, {msg2: '...'})
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    })
```

Comment: Could you demonstrate that with code? not quite sure how I can implement that.

Comment: yes, sure, I work on that and I will post a solution soon